# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: object is not iterable... when using await Promise.all(promises);

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to generate PNG asynchronously with NodeJS.

```
async generateAnnualPNG(recap) {
    let promises = [];
    console.log("Generating images for annual reports")
    for (const meter of recap.meters) {
        const url = process.env.BASE_URL + "operations/" + recap.operation.name + "/meters/" + meter.prm + "/annual_individual_report";
        promises.push(this.makePngScreenshot(recap, url, meter.prm, "annual_2019-2020"));
    }
    return promises
},
```

with `makePngScreenshot`:

```
async makePngScreenshot(recap, url, meterId, filename) {
        axios.get(url, null); // Make the request to generate html page
        const destination = "public/images/" + recap.operation.name + "/" + recap.date_ini + "_" + recap.date_end + "/" + meterId
        return new Pageres({ delay: 2, filename: filename })
            .src(url, ['1300x650'], { crop: true })
            .dest(destination)
            .run()

    }
```

When I debug, I can see that the returned promises seems OK, it is an array of 7 pending promises.

I call it from:

```
module.exports = {

    async generatePNGs(recap) {
        let promises = [];
        promises = this.generateAnnualPNG(recap)

        await Promise.all(promises);
        console.log("Done generating images")
    },
```

I never see `Done generating images` message... Why ?

Here is the log:

```
Generating images for annual reports
images.js:53
(node:571426) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at Object.generatePNGs (/home/julien/Code/customer_recap/images.js:17:34)
    at init (/home/julien/Code/customer_recap/index.js:113:44)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
<node_internals>/internal/process/warning.js:32
(node:571426) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
<node_internals>/internal/process/warning.js:32
(node:571426) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `generateAnnualPNG(recap)`  return Promises array? maybe it returns another object?

Comment: Yes, I double checked. generateAnnualPNG is returning an array of pending promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `promises` in `generatePNGs` is not actually an Array, it's a `Promise<Array>`.** You can await it, but you should probably just remove `async` from `generateAnnualPNG`.

---

```js
async makePngScreenshot(recap, url, meterId, filename) {
  /* ... */
  return new Pageres(/*...*/).src(/*...*/).dest(/*...*/).run()
}
```

`makePngScreenshot` is `async`, therefore it absolutely returns a `Promise`.

```js
async generateAnnualPNG(recap) {
    let promises = [];
    /* ... */
    for (const meter of recap.meters) {
        const url = /* ... */
        promises.push(this.makePngScreenshot(/* ... */));
    }
    return promises
}
```

`generateAnnualPNG` is also `async`, so it absolutely returns a Promise. Evidently the promise resolves to an array of promises, because it populates an Array of the objects that `makePngScreenshot` returns.

This means that despite you setting `promises` to be an Array, you've actually set it to be a Promise.

```js
async generatePNGs(recap) {
  let promises = [];                         // this was an array
  promises = this.generateAnnualPNG(recap)   // but now it's a promise

  await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log("Done generating images")
}
```

Your best choice is to remove `async` from `generateAnnualPNG`'s definition. Though it's working with promises, it's not `await`ing anything, and at that point `generateAnnualPNG` will return an array of promises rather than a promise of an array (of promises). That list would work the way `generatePNGs` expects, and you could pass that array directly into `Promise.all` as you do above.

As an alternative, you could also change `generatePNGs` to `await this.generateAnnualPNG(/* ... */)`, which you would only need to do if your list is not ready synchronously (i.e. you don't know how many promises are in the list you're returning). At that point there's very little value in returning a promise of an array of promises; you can `await promises` within `generateAnnualPNG` so that the return value of `generateAnnualPNG` is a promise to an array of *values*. The only reason you'd do otherwise is if you have UI or logging that would benefit from showing incremental progress.

Final note: it looks like `makePngScreenshot` is also `async` without actually `await`ing anything. If that's a bug in your current code, don't forget to add `await` where needed (e.g. to your `axios.get` call).

Comment: Exactly ! Thanks for enlightment ;)